# GNOME Terminal always opens maximised

Tags: gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, window-manager, maximized

I have a small but annoying problem that I just can't figure out.

I have two installations of Ubuntu 18.04. One on my laptop, one on my desktop.

Whenever I open `gnome-terminal` on my desktop it defaults to being a maximised window. I know some people like it maximised by default (and there are plenty of forum posts etc. advising how this might be done), but I personally want it to appear in a small window.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to let go of this behavior. I checked the Man pages for command line arguments I might specify, but nothing. I don't know where it has picked up this habit.

Anyone care to enlighten me as to where the application might be getting this instruction? And how I might turn it off?

Just to mention, if I create another user account and log in with that, this does not happen. As such, something in my own profile must be driving it.. just not sure where to look.

Comment: Check Preferences -> (the default profile) -> Initial terminal size.

Comment: 80 columns, 24 rows. I hit "Reset" and it did not change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nautilus normally remembers the last Window size. If a window size is near to filling the screen, Gnome Shell (used by Ubuntu 18.04) will automatically maximize. If that is the cause, then turn this of in org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize. With the terminal:

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize false`

To undo:

`gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize`

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me and nothing changed applying the solutions of the answers above, but I realized that if you are using Maximus to undecorate de maximized windows, you have to disable the no_maximize option (Do not automatically maximize newly opened windows. If undecorate is set, will still undecorate maximised windows.) using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> [gconf-editor] / > apps> Maximus.