# Title bar disappears on some applications when maximizing some windows in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, firefox, window, titlebar

Title bar disappears on some applications when maximizing some windows. It mainly happens when I maximize application windows.

For instance, when the System Monitor is maximized the title bar remains but when Firefox is maximized the title bar disappears. Even worse, the same thing happens in Spotify but with Spotify I can't even get it to change size after I've maximized it because the title bar is gone.

Comment: The only GNOME extensions I have installed is User Themes. I've noticed the windows are acting even more abnormal. it seems like the title bar is like hidden behind the menu bar because if I drag down from the menu bar in certain locations I can grab the title bar of the window. Another odd thing I never really thought about but my terminal will always open maximized even though I have never changed any setting and I cant seem to find why that happens either.

Comment: The other issue sounds like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074678/gnome-terminal-always-opens-maximised

Comment: You should be able to grab the window by clicking on the dash bar and dragging down.

Comment: Also, have you tried double clicking on your top dash bar (menu bar).

Answer (score 2):

[GNOME Terminal always opens maximised](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074678/gnome-terminal-always-opens-maximised) did lead me to the answer it was with a program Maximus I had installed to run some games in fullscreen windowed mode that I don't even use anymore so after purging it and rebooting all problems had been fixed. If you are using Maximus and want to continue using it for other purposes than hiding title bars I did also figure out that pressing Alt+Space+X will bring them back.

Comment: Alt + Space + X it is. It happened with Foxit Reader - the title bar just got missing. Good info, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is still present on Ubuntu 23.4. on setup with multiple monitors with different resolutions. Atl + Space + X does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue. I work with two monitors and need to move application windows, especially Chrome and Firefox browser windows, frequently among the monitors. This is achievable by two methods:

1. [Shift] + [Super] + arrow keys [Left|Right|Up|Down]
2. Right-Click title bar and click on "Move to Monitor [Left|Right|Up|Down]"

Sometime few months back, the title bar suddenly disappeared for some maximized windows. It was tortuous for me to use the keyboard method frequently. I had been looking everywhere for a solution to "unmerge" the title bar from the tab bar or to always show it.

Today, I found a simple solution for my setup of Ubuntu 18.04 using the Ambiance theme. Here are the steps I did.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/index.theme
```

In the above file, the last line was as below:

```
X-Ubuntu-UseOverlayScrollbars=true
```

I changed above to:

```
X-Ubuntu-UseOverlayScrollbars=false
```

and saved the file.

And, my issue was resolved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to grab the window by clicking on the dash bar and dragging down.

Additionally, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>  and/or <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+ will maximize and unmaximize a window. You can also hold down the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key and drag anywhere in a window to move it.

However, For Firefox there is a setting to remove or include a title bar.

Go to "Menu" > "Customize" > and then untick the box to *disable* "Title Bar" (on the lower left side).

It may seem counterintuitive to disable the title bar. However, when you disable the title bar in Firefox, the window buttons will display on the window in the tab bar area, even when the window is maximized. Additionally, double clicking on any blank space next to your tabs will unmaximize/maximize the window and the tab area will function as the title bar.

<sub>Also, you may need to make sure that "Drag Space" is disabled and if your window buttons disappear after changing these settings, just close Firefox and reopen the application.</sub>

[Ubuntu help docs (maximize and unmaximize a window).](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-maximize.html.en#:%7E:text=To%20maximize%20a%20window%2C%20grab,the%20edges%20of%20the%20screen.)

[Gnome help docs (maximize and unmaximize a window).](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-windows-maximize.html.en#:%7E:text=To%20maximize%20a%20window%20using,%2C%20or%20press%20Alt%20%2B%20F10%20.)

[Ubuntuhandbook.org (hide firefox title bar)](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/hide-firefox-title-bar-ubuntu-18-0416-04/)